# Convexity of $f(x) = \log \left( \sum_{i = 1}^N \varepsilon_i\left( Q(a_i + b_i\sqrt x ) \right) ^2 \right)$

Tags: convex-analysis

I know that for $x,a,b\ge0$; ${Q({a_i} + {b_i}\sqrt x )}^2$ holds convexity because the $Q$ function holds the convexity (monotonicity) . I dont know how should I approach to prove

$$\log \left( \sum_{i = 1}^N \varepsilon_i\left( Q(a_i + b_i\sqrt x ) \right) ^2 \right)$$

is convex for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: If $N=1$, $Q(x)=x$, $a=0$, $b=1$, $\epsilon=1$ then the new function is $\log{x}$ hence not convex.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. As logx is concave so I can say the function I mentioned in the above section is strictly concave. Is it straight forward like that?

Comment: I don't think you can conclude anything for such a general Q. What exactly do you assume about Q? You are not being very precise about it.